# Notifications between rest api

Tags: c#, azure-notificationhub, rest

Can a rest api send notifications to external rest api's, for example through Azure notifications?

Or is the best solution to have external api's, third parties, polling the api for updates?

My api runs in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're APIs are running within Azure, I suggest looking at using Azure [Storage Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-tutorial-queues?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet) or [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) triggers. One rest API can write an object payload to to said queue/service bus and any subscribed functions will pick that payload up and process the message data.